I have an apps scripts web app which gets a json object in return from a POST call and it creates google slides , how do I let any one access it?
I've tried multiple different options but either get 401 errors or 403 errors when I link it with a GCP project, maybe I am doing something wrong?
I want the slides and sheets to be created in the user's account so I set it up as user accessing the web app and access to anyone with a google account. It uses a template to create a slide and I made sure the template is public too.Below are the AuthScopes :
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents"
  ]

And here is how I'm accessing the web app :
               def create_and_open_presentation(api_url, json_output):
                    response = requests.post(api_url, json=json_output)
                
                    if response.status_code == 200:
                        presentation_url = response.text.strip()
                        st.write(f"Presentation created: {presentation_url}")
                        webbrowser.open(presentation_url)
                    else:
                        st.write(f"Failed to create presentation. Status code: {response.status_code}")
                        st.write(f"Response: {response.text}")
                
                api_url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxHuTnPpGQrVDg08Bk5Bv0vLXZkRpaJWMxEI1UytHkmGRcLWN_00sIflJ2jUxeL3LEO/exec'
                create_and_open_presentation(api_url, json_output)

Can someone help me as to what exactly to do?
The end goal is to host it on a website but I'd like to test it out on local host first. I did try authorising it with an extra account of mine added as a tester account too but it just gave me 403 errors regardless. Desperately need the guidance.
I tried setting up a gap project with the OAuth screen and all to no avail. Documentations did not help me much either as I'm new to apes scripts. Please help me.

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In your title, you say how do I let any one access it?. But, in your question, you say I set it up as user accessing the web app and access to anyone with a google account. Can I ask you about the details of your expected result?

Oh i'm sorry, I meant that I basically want other users to be able to use my tool.which utilizes the script through a website of mine.  I want ny script to be excepted without any 401 or 403 errors, and the slides and charts created should stay in their drive.

Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.
